# Run playing game in full-screen on one display, Unity IDE in another

Tags: unity

I have multiple monitors (*). If the Unity (2018.1) IDE is open and maximized in one of them, is there an easy way to have it use one of the OTHER displays to run the game full-screen whenever I launch 'play' mode? Or alternatively, to undock the "Game" tab from the IDE & turn it into a normal window that can be moved to an adjacent display & maximized?

---

(*) If it matters, I'm running Windows 10, with the desktop extended across all three. The left and middle (main) displays are connected via DVI, the right display is my laptop (Dell Precision m4800 with Quadro K2100M). All three are 1920x1080.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly, but you can drag&drop the game tab anywhere you want, including another screen.

Comment: Thanks, go ahead and post that as an answer & I'll accept it. That worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabs in the editor, including the game and scene tabs, can be detached and moved via drag&drop. If moved outside the editor window, e.g. onto another screen, they become separate windows and can be maximized/restored or closed.